# Expect - Direct output of remote command to local file

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, expect, fifo

I am trying to call an expect script from bash in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo foobar
expectScript > foobar &
# other stuff that does stuff with foobar
```

What expectScript needs to do is to ssh into a remote host.  From there it needs to ssh into another remote host.  Then it needs to switch user to root (root login is not permitted).  Then it needs to issue a command (e.g. tail -f /var/log/messages) that ultimately needs to be written to foobar.  Nothing else can be written to foobar, e.g. password prompts or command prompts.  Only the output of the command can be written to foobar.  I have the login portion of the script working fine.  What I am struggling with is how to make it so that the output is written to foobar, and in such a way that SIGINT will kill the command.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set HOST1_USER myuser
set HOST2_USER myotheruser
set HOST1_PASSWORD mypassword
set HOST2_PASSWORD myotherpassword
set ROOT_PASSWORD anotherpassword
set HOST1 192.168.0.5
# HOST2 is only reachable from HOST1
set HOST2 192.168.1.12

global until_interrupt
set until_interrupt 0

set HOST1_PROMPT "CL-\\d.*#"
set HOST2_PROMPT "\\\$ $"
set ROOT_PROMPT "# $"

log_user 0

spawn ssh $HOST1_USER@$HOST1
#   ssh keys are exchanged with HOST1, so there is no need for password here
    expect -re "$HOST1_PROMPT" {
            send "ssh HOST2_USER@$HOST2\n"
            expect {
                    -re ".*ssword.*" { send "$HOST2_PASSWORD\n" }
                    -re ".*Are you sure you want to continue connecting.*" {send "yes\n"; exp_continue}
            }
    }

    expect -re "$HOST2_PROMPT" { send "su\n" }
    expect -re ".*ssword.*" { send "ROOT_PASSWORD\n" }

    log_user 1
    # nothing up to this point should have been sent to stdout
    # now I want the output of the tail command to be sent to stdout

    expect -re "$ROOT_PROMPT" { send "tail -f /var/log/messages\n" }

    # I want to wait here until SIGINT is sent.  There may be a better way than the traps below.
    # Set a trap to watch for SIGINT
    trap {
            set until_interrupt sigint_detected
    } SIGINT

    while { $until_interrupt == 0 } {
            #wait until sigint
    }

    send "\003"
    # I think that is SIGINT, and that I'm sending it because I caught the first one in the trap.

    trap {
            exit
    } SIGINT

    set timeout 30

    expect -re "$ROOT_PROMPT" { send "exit\n" }
    expect -re "$HOST2_PROMPT" { send "exit\n" }
    expect -re "$HOST1_PROMPT" { send "exit\n" }
    # Fully exited
```

Comment: Most of this `expect` script can be eliminated simply by using public-key authentication and the tunneling support built in to `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks chepner, but not much can be eliminated because on HOST2 I need to run the command as root (sudo won't work), and HOST2 does not allow root to log in over ssh.  So it is necessary to first log in as a non-root user then su to root.  I have implemented the solution on hosts where public-key authentication works, and it is much easier.  But for this particular server, I don't see how it could work.

Comment: If you have the root password, you can *configure* `sudo` to work.  And there is nothing preventing you from setting the correct user ids and host names in your local `ssh` config file.

Comment: Thanks chepner.  I am logging into a system for which I cannot make such modifications for sudo, even though I have the root password.

Comment: There is also one other caveat that prevents me from avoiding expect altogether, or I would definitely go the route you have suggested.  Even after I log in as root, there is another command I need to run that cannot be combined as command1; command2.  (command1 is vrctl, so sets the context for command2.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an `expect` for the echo of the control character you send to the remote (or some other string not being produced by your `tail -f` command).  For example this simple `ssh` example works for me (the `-d` is for debug):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
log_user 0
spawn ssh localhost
expect " $ "
send "tail -f /var/log/messages\n"
log_user 1
trap {  send "\003" } SIGINT
set timeout -1
expect "\003"
expect "$ "
send "date\r"
expect "$ "
```

If I run this, redirecting stdin to null, in the background of the shell I can type Ctrl-C and it ends cleanly.

```
./prog </dev/null >/tmp/out &
```